# Multiple columns and offset array to list in ComboBox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, multiple-columns

My lack of experience is really starting to show. So please excuse my inexperience, however, I have received some help on this in a previous thread.

The code that was send does work, although when I delved into the functions. I came evident that in the spreadsheet I have I needed to produce a uniqueID to re-surface the data and update the information held within different tabs.

So what I have from the code below is a list of UniqueID's based on a criteria, however, I need to be able to produce a similar list, offsetting the returned data from Column "B", to Colum "A" (ie Column1 "UniqueID", Column2 "TaksName")

Sample Code:

```
Public Function TaskList()

Call SetVariables

If Not Me.CB_Creator.Value = "" And Not IsEmpty(CB_Creator.Value) Then

For rCount = LBound(vDat) To UBound(vDat)
    If Not vDat(rCount, 13) = "Published" And vDat(rCount, 9) = CB_Creator Then
    rDict1(vDat(rCount, 2)) = vDat(rCount, 2)
    rDict2(vDat(rCount, 1)) = vDat(rCount, 2)
    End If

Next rCount

Else
   
End If

CB_TaskList.List = rDict.Keys

End Function
```

The next element is the ComboBox (CB_TaskList), which will have two colums to contain the data from the lists above:

Column 1 = rDict1.keys
Column 2 = rDict2.Keys

```
CB_TaskList.ColumnCount = 2
CB_TaskList.ColumnWidths = "40;80"
CB_TaskList.List(1.0)=rDict1.Keys or CB_TaskList.Column(1)=rDict1.keys (Both Fail)
CB_TaskList.List(1,1)= rDict2.keys or CB_TaskList.Column(2)=rDict2.keys (Both Fail)
```

Any assistance would be gratefully received

Answer (score 0):

After hours on the Internet I have finally managed to resolve this problem and thought I would share my result.

```
Public Function TaskList()

Call SetVariables

With CB_TaskList
.ColumnCount = 2
.ColumnWidths = "60;110"
.BoundColumn = 1
.TextColumn = 2
End With

 If Not Me.CB_Creator.Value = "" And Not IsEmpty(CB_Creator.Value) Then

    For rCount = LBound(vDat) To UBound(vDat)
    If Not vDat(rCount, 13) = "Published" And vDat(rCount, 9) = CB_Creator Then
              
        If Not rDict.Exists(vDat(rCount, 2)) Then
            rDict(vDat(rCount, 2)) = vDat(rCount, 2)
            CB_TaskList.AddItem vDat(rCount, 2)
            CB_TaskList.List(CB_TaskList.ListCount - 1, 1) = vDat(rCount, 1)
        End If
        End If

    Next rCount
 End If

 End Function
```